# name that has biggest number

Tags: command-line, text

I have a file with a list of names and a number next to it separated by a space for exemple:

```
Mat 199
rose 150
```

I want to display the name that has the biggest number next to, so in this exemple, display `Mat`. Also note that there's 1 name and number per line in the file and the command can only use 1 pipe.

Comment: Why would the command only need to use one pipe?

Comment: @terdon because it is school work perhaps

Answer (score 4):

There's no need for any pipe:

```
awk -v max=0 '{if($2>max){name=$1; max=$2}}END{print name}' file
```

Note that this assumes that the largest numerical value in the file is positive and that there is at least one line with two fields in the file, where the second field is numerical.

Answer (score 2):

```
sort -k2 -nr myfileName.txt | head -1
```